# DJANGO | How to make the object in the application take the value of the name when viewing the list

Tags: python, django, object, admin

https://i.stack.imgur.com/30M2y.jpg - **Image Admin Panel**

Admin Code:

```
from django.contrib import admin
from .models import Destination

admin.site.register(Destination)
```

Summery:
I did dynamic migration to the main page. I want the name of the destination to be accepted in the list in admin panel.
How to do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolved problem:

```
from django.contrib import admin
from .models import Destination

class DestinationAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ('name',) #I taking value from list of object.

admin.site.register(Destination, DestinationAdmin)
```

> Nekain helped me